# python : comma in print as "\t"

Tags: python

the `,` in print added a white space

```
>>> print "a","b"
a b
```

If I need a `\t`, I put

```
>>> print "a","\t","b"
a       b
```

How I can change the output of `,` to a `\t`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import the `print()` function from `__future__` and use `sep='\t'`, `print()` function was introduced in python 3, and it replaced the `print` statement used in python 2.x:

```
In [1]: from __future__ import print_function

In [2]: print('a','b',sep='\t')
a   b
```

help on `print()`:

```
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

> ```
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
> Optional keyword arguments:
> file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
> sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
> end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead:

```
print '\t'.join(('a', 'b'))
```

The python `print` statement will convert any element in the expression to string and join them using a space; if you want to use a different delimiter you'll have to do the joining manually.

Alternatively, use the [`print()` *function*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), which has been introduced to ease transition to Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('a','b',sep='\t')
```

The `print()` function accepts a `sep` parameter to alter what string is used to delimit the values. In python 3, only the `print()` function remains and the old `print` statement from python 2 has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way

```
print("%s\t%s",%(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print

like this `print "Hello", "workd!",`